# $f(x_0)=\sup\limits_{x\in{X}}\, f(x)$ in a compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Suppose that $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is such that for all convergent sequences $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subseteq X$ , $f(\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\, x_n)\geq \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\, \sup\, f(x_n)$ . Show that there is an $x_0\in{X}$ such that $f(x_0)=\sup\limits_{x\in{X}}\, f(x)$.

How do we proceed on this?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $M= \sup_{x\in X} f(x)$. Then there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ such that $M = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$. Since $X$ compact, we may assume that $x_n$ converges to some $x_0\in X$. We have

$$M\ge f(x_0)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) \ge \limsup_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = M$$
That is $f(x_0) =M$.